# Button onclick get request to invoke getIndex()

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, http, get

I have a button which should perform a get request to '/index'.
Then my page should call getIndex via a routing method, which should render index.html.

```
    <div>
        <script> function goToHome(){ 
            $.get("/index");
        }
        </script>

        <button type="button" onclick="goToHome()">
            Go to the dashboard!
        </button>   
    </div>

router.get('/index', Routemethods.getIndex);

exports.getIndex = function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');
}
```

However, the request is made, and getindex is being called (logged to see if it did). The problem is that my page is not being reloaded to index.html. What am I doing wrong? I made it work using href but not a big fan of that approach.

Comment: If you are navigating via the url it is way better to navigate via hrefs instead of having js do the request. This gracefully degrades and users will be able to navigate your site even if js for some reason is not working.

Comment: I think you need to use a rendering engine like Jade

Comment: Rendering engine I use is ejs and works fine when performing a get request via the url, but I don't really want to navigate via the url (as in users need to enter the url themselves)

Or as shown below, it is possible to still do it with some sort of button? Just like how I can click on my profile on for example forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified if this is node or jquery on the browser. This seems like an ajax call, not navigation.

```
   <script> function goToHome(){ 
        $.get("/index");
    }
    </script>
```

This will make your browser request the page

```
   function goToHome(){
         window.location.href = '/index'; // this might need tweaking based on your servers setup, paths, etc
   }
```

But as stated before, you could do this with a link and the correct href. You shouldn't offload this to a button and js unless there is a good reason for this. You are using more memory and making navigation dependent on js.

Comment: I want to be able to navigate through some sort of dashboard, like "My profile" and "My bids" (users are able to get offers). So I figure'd I'd do this with buttons.

But not sure what the 'best practice' is in this case.. Will try your suggestion tomorrow. I've got my routes setup on express/nodejs and the html is displayed to the user. As stated I could just href to localhost:3014/index for navigating? (Still locally hosted for now)

Comment: Indeed, I can navigate using href/buttons so I think I've got it sorted out. :)
But I see what you mean, better "construct" a button with css. Thanks!